# Use static analysis to find all assignments to a given field

Tags: typescript, compilation, cross-compiling, abstract-syntax-tree, preprocessor

I'm thinking of ways to do databinding in Typescript without using dirty checking or generating getters and setters. I'm trying to determine if it would be possible (assuming full use of type annotations) to find all the places a certain field of a certain class is assigned to using static analysis. The purpose would be to generate calls to  functions that handle the databinding behind the scenes which would remove clutter from the instances when inspected and be nicer on the runtime because getters/setters (as I recall) are harder for the VM to optimize than property assignments.

For example

```
export class Vector3 {

    public x : number;
    public y : number;
    public z : number;
}

var v0 = new Vector3();
v0.x = 1;
//generate call to Databindings.set(v0, 'x', v0.x);

function addX(a : Vector3, val : number) : void {
    a.x += val;
    //generate call to Databindings.set(a, 'x', a.x);
}

addX(a, 10);
```

I'm almost certain that I can figure out how to find all assignments to instances of Vector3's `x` property, but unsure how it would work inside function calls like `addX` where the instance variable is aliased.

What are some ways in which I can approach this problem? Assume I already have an AST for my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property decorators with [rtti](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4) or can use aspect-oriented programming [sample](https://aspect.codeplex.com/)

```
function bind(target: Object, propertyKey: string) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
        get: function () {
            return value;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            value = val;
            console.log("call Databindings.set(this, " + propertyKey + ", " + val + ")");
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}

class Vector3 {
    @bind
    public x : number;
    @bind
    public y : number;
    @bind
    public z : number;
}

var v0 = new Vector3();
v0.x = 1;
//generate call to Databindings.set(v0, 'x', v0.x);

function addX(a : Vector3, val : number) : void {
    a.x += val;
    //generate call to Databindings.set(a, 'x', a.x);
}

addX(v0, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm trying to avoid generating getters / setters. I'd really like to figure this out at build time if thats possible

Comment: You can't get setting value at build time. What kind of AST do you have? You can write postprocessor using typescript AST API. In general, you will not have class of object. `let arr: IXProp[] = [{x: 0}, new Vector3()]; for (let key of arr) key.x = 5;`